# How to build jar artifact so at run-time it will be able to read packed files?

Tags: java, jar

At run-time application successfully files at project's root. All  works fine when executing project in IntelliJ but when built jar artifact by IntelliJ executed in Windows environment it has troubles locating/reading files although they reside in root of jar file. How to fix it?

**UPDATE**
I am using Jersey framework. I read file from root path like that:

```
package example;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

@Path("/monitor")
public class MonitoringPage {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getMonitoringPage() throws IOException {

        String page, line;
        page = "";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("MonitoringPage.htm"));
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            page += line + "\r\n";
        }
        br.close();
        return page;
    }
}
```

My jar has MonitoringPage.htm in it's root but it cannot find it for some strange reason.

I am running jar with bat script:

```
java -jar "Rs.jar"
```

.

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51


Path=.......**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin**
```

[image]

Comment: Would you care to share some code in the normal stackoverflow manner? I'm sure whatever image you've embedded is very nice but many of us are behind proxies that block image sharing sites and can't see it.

Comment: Which files are you loading and how are you loading them from code and what's your classpath like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't read it as a file from the file system (as is what happens when you use `File`, `FileReader` or many of its `FileXxx` variants). Once you package the jar, the file will no long be in the system file location you are expecting

Instead read it as a resource via an `URL`. You can use:

- `MonitoringPage.class.getResourceAsStream("/MonitoringPage.htm")` which will return an `InputStream`.

From that `InputStream` you can just do something like

```
InputStream is = MonitoringPage.class.getResourceAsStream("/MonitoringPage.htm");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

Note: this is all assuming you have the file at the root of the classpath (which it looks like from your image). The `/` in the front of the path will bring the search to the root of the classpath. So just use the path to the file that's relative to the root

Comment: Thanks, it opens fine from jar but new problem emerged `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.Reader.<init>`  at `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));`. Why file cannot be read while being run in IntelliJ?

Comment: I don't use intellij so I'm not sure how the resources get built to the IDE runtime. For instance, in Eclipse, all the files in the `src` get copied to a `bin` directory (when you try and run), which is the root of the class pat, and where all the `.class` files get compiled to. So you need to check where all your class files go when they compile from the IDE. And see if the file gets copied there